# NSS Secret (symmetric) Key Import

Tags: cryptography, fips, nss

I am trying to figure out how to import a symmetric key into NSS for use with encryption at the core crypto boundary. These functions are described 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Reference/NSS_cryptographic_module/FIPS_mode_of_operation
I have been able to do every other type of crypto operation by following the documentation because it mirrors PKCS 11  described here:
http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/cos01/pkcs11-base-v2.40-cos01.html
However attempting to import any template where the CK_OBJECT_CLASS" is "CKO_SECRET_KEY" always returns "CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID 0x00000013". But I have no problem with assymetric (public/private)

```
CK_RV crv;
CK_FUNCTION_LIST_PTR pFunctionList;
CK_OBJECT_CLASS keyClass = CKO_SECRET_KEY;
CK_ATTRIBUTE keyTemplate[] = {
  {CKA_CLASS, &keyClass, sizeof(keyClass)}
};
crv = pFunctionList->C_CreateObject(hRwSession, keyTemplate, 1, &hKey);
printf("failed with 0x%08X\n", crv);
```

But according to the documentation this should be returning "CKR_TEMPLATE_INCOMPLETE" as "CKO_SECRET_KEY" is a valid object class.

Again I have had no trouble with assymetric. I should Also point out that my function pointers is for FIPS mode only. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code you pasted is either incomplete or simply wrong. In particular, there's no concrete value for the key you're creating in the template (CKA_VALUE), which can easily cause the error you're getting from C_CreateObject.